# WebKitGTK not installed / unknown version detected

Tags: pantheon-mail, development, vala

Trying to build pantheon-mail I bump into this error when running `cmake`.

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:493 (message):
  WebKitGTK not installed / unknown version detected
```

Which version of WebKitGTK should be installed and what is the exact apt package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: `sudo apt-get build-dep pantheon-mail` installs all dev dependencies.